# Apache POI. How do I set the page layout / paper size for a Word document?

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to create a Word document from scratch using the Apache POI package. Outputting simply-formatted text has not proved to be a problem but I would like to change the page size.

How do I set the page layout / paper size for a Word document?

Can anyone point me to useful examples for using POI to create Word documents?

Answer (score 2):

For example if you want to set the A4-format you can use this code:

```
 Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# with NPOI I use

```
document.PageLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Landscape;
```

or

```
document.PageLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Portrait;
```